# 400 Watt or 700 Watt Speacker is best choice for special room?

Tags: sound-design, audio, sound-effects, sound, speakers

I‌ want to buy a 12-inch dB‌ series  [Opera 512 DX Speaker](http://www.dbtechnologies.com/en/products/opera-dx/opera-512-dx-p718.aspx) that be a 400 watt speaker or [Opera 712 DX](http://www.dbtechnologies.com/en/products/opera-dx/opera-712-dx-p720.aspx) that be a 700 watt speaker for a room with 90 Square Meter Area and has a height of 3 Meter. The material of this room is plaster and the aria is not acoustic. My work is live vocal or singing. in addition the people that seat on this room is up to 100 persons. the distance between the speaker and singer is up to 8 meter.

> Which one is produce a good choice and give the best quality sound for my
>   room, 400 or 700 watt‌?‌ I‌ want to buy just single speaker. is there any technical point here?

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Which one is produce a good choice and give the best quality sound for
>   my room, 400 or 700 watt‌?‌ I‌ want to buy just single speaker. is
>   there any technical point here?

Product recommendations are probably out of scope of the SE-site.

But let me give you my opinion on wattage vs room-size.

**For a 90 square-meter room, you are probably good with anything of 50 Watts and above. It is a reasonable small room, and your audience is only 100 people.**

However it now going to depend on a couple of factors:

- Is your performance the main reason the audience is in the room?
- Are they all sitting/standing still, full attention to the performance, and no to little background noise, or noise pollution ?
- Or is this a bar, where your performance is more a background music and your audience are socially talking to eachother, hence your performance must at least over come (some) the noise the audience is creating ?

These factors are determining on how "loud" your performance must sound.

The two choices you give, 400 Watts / 700 Watts, probably have plenty of "headroom" to cater for anything like that, and are probably overkill to some extend.

**The best advise I can give you** is to go to a pro-audio re-seller and actually setup the gear in a room of comparable size. Test the equipment, and have someone else perform (or use a recording) to hear the sound yourself prior to buying anything.

**Example** I have been in situations like this, about 100 people, where the performance was not the main attraction of the venue (hence had to overcome noises generated by the attendee's, but not too loud to disrupt personal/social conversations) and I have used a single 400 Watt system, where the final amplifier would only work at 10-15% of its capacity (to describe it in a simple way, **[edit based on comments]** *this is only to be taken as an example, not scientific method of determining power output of an amplifier*)

*"Your mileage may vary"*

Comment: you means 700 Watt is very very loud sound for this area? isn't it?

Comment: 700 Watts full will burst peoples ear-drums, and the plaster on the walls will crumble.... re-read the sentence in **bold** above :-)

Comment: "where the final amplifier would only work at 10-15% of its capacity". How were you able to measure that?

Comment: @Johannes, I didn't measure it. I recall using very little amlification in the order of 10-15% of the gain control of the final amp. I used this in my answer to highlight what power you need for a room as described by the OP, I did not use this as a scientific measurement.

Comment: Yes, but the position of the volume control has nothing to do with the amount of amplification that is taking place. It is entirely possible to have an amp clip with the volume at 9 o'clock, for instance.

Comment: @Johannes, yes, but that was not the conclusion of my answer. The advice to go to a reputable reseller and test would be my answer in this case. It is entirely possible to clip an amplifier at any level of "knob". I just used it as an example, that is all: my amp did not clip and my system was setup with proper gain structure. And in my **proffessional opinion** the amp which could deliver 400 Watts RMS with the appropriate speaker, at that situation, was only producing 40-50-maybe-60 Watts maximum.... Unless you have another answer, another advice, then please post your answer.

Comment: You said "I recall using very little amlification in the order of 10-15% of the gain control of the final amp." which is severly misleading since it has nothing to do with the power used. And you say it is your professional opinion that the system was outputting only 40-60 W. Well, without any kind of power meter you simply cannot know that. You are simply waving your hands.

Answer (score 1):

As you will need rather modest amounts of power to put sound into your room (likely well less than 100W), the power rating of the speaker(s) is the LEAST important factor in selecting a speaker.

There are dozens of more important factors, and most of them are ACOUSTIC and have nothing to do with the speaker.

You say "area is not acoustic", but we don't know what that means? How important is definition (intelligibility)? If the room is very reverberant and/or if there is much background noise, then no speaker will perform well. You must treat the room acoustics to provide a suitable environment for the speaker to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that doubling the amplifier power only increases sound level by 3dB. So all else being equal, I don't think you'd gain much by choosing the 700w model over the 400w, especially since your scenario doesn't require high volume levels or a lot of deep bass frequencies.